# Vuejs/Nuxtjs watch is unable to watch for changes within the Array of Objects from Vuex Store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex, watch

I am developing an application using `Vuejs/Nuxtjs` within this application I have a component `IdentifiersNode.vue` within that I would like to watch for a Vuex Store array `identifiersArray`.

I am able to watch the `identifiersArray` for direct changes such as `push, direct key-value changes` but when I add a new object to the object within the `identifiersArray` then `watch` would not work for some reason.

Following is the `watch` function in my `IdentifiersNode.vue`:

```
watch: {
    '$store.state.modules.identifiersInfoStore.identifiersArray': {
        handler (val) {
            console.log('WATCH : ' + JSON.stringify(val, null, 4))
        },
        deep: true
    }
},
```

Following are the changes happening to my `identifiersArray` within the `Vuex Store Mutations` present in `identifiersInfoStore .js`:

```
saveIdentifiersInfo (state, payload) {
    // Upon saving the Identifiers info save the information into respective object of identifiersArray
    const identifiersNode = state.identifiersArray.find(node => node.identifiersId === state.currentNodeId)

    console.log('NODE BEFORE : ' + JSON.stringify(identifiersNode, null, 4))
    
    identifiersNode.instanceData = payload.instanceData
    
    console.log('NODE ARRAY AFTER : ' + JSON.stringify(state.identifiersArray, null, 4))
},
```

As we can see I am adding an object to an existing object within the `identifiersArray` but when I do this I would expect my `watch` function to trigger in `IdentifiersNode.vue` as I have `deep: true` but for some reason, it does not work at all.

Can someone please tell me if it's possible to detect even a minute change to an array using the `Vuex store` and `Vue watch`? If not then what is an alternative that I can take?

Following is my `identifiersNode` from console.log:

```
NODE BEFORE : {
    "identifiersId": 1,
    "name": "identifiersNode1"
}
```

Following is the `state.identifiersArray` from console.log:

```
NODE ARRAY AFTER : [
    {
        "identifiersId": 1,
        "name": "identifiersNode1",
        "instanceData": {
            "name": "Batman",
            "job":"IT"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Did you try using Vue.set method?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov I tried the `Vue.set` but the problem that I am facing is when I do `Vue.set` is pushing the new object to an array instead of appending the existing object. Can you please let me know how to append to an existing object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the answer can be helpful to someone else in the future.

I was actually appending the object to an existing object in Array within Vuex Store. Hence, the watch was not able to identify the change. I changed it to `vue.set` which worked for me.

Previously I was using to append to my existing object:

```
identifiersNode.instanceData = payload.instanceData
```

Later I changed to:

```
// Use the Vue reactive approach to add the instanceData object to existing object
Vue.set(identifiersNode, 'instanceData', payload.instanceData)
```

Following is my watch in Vue component, I used this code within my `mounted` can also be used within watch as well:

```
// Watch for the changes on the identifiers array 
this.$watch('$store.state.modules.identifiersInfoStore.identifiersArray', (val) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(val,null,4))
}, { immediate: true, deep: true })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vuex, I would recommand using `mapGetters` to get your items from the store. This will automatically watch the values and re-render each time your items changes.

Here is the documentation : [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters)

## Little example

### Store

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = {
  data: ["Hello", "world"]
};

const mutations = {
  addItem(state, item) {
    state.data.push(item);
  }
};

const getters = {
  getData: (state) => state.data
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
})
```

### Component

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>{{ data }}</h2>

    <input type="text" v-model="inputValue" />
    <button @click="addItemToStore">add item</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      data: "getData",
    }),
  },

  data: () => {
    return {
      inputValue: "",
    };
  },

  methods: {
    addItemToStore() {
      this.addItem(this.inputValue);
      this.inputValue = "";
    },
    ...mapMutations({
      addItem: "addItem",
    }),
  },
};
</script>
```

Here is a codepen as an example : https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-store-forked-bl9rk0?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

If you want to change an object property (Or in your case addind a new object to an array which is a property of your object) the best thing to do is completely re-push the current object.

for example if you have an array like `[{id: 1, values: [1,2,3]}, {id: 2, values: [4,5,6]}]` you can update values with the [js splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) :

```js
addValue(state, {id, valueToAdd}){
   const pos = state.arr.findIndex(x => x.id === id)
   if (pos !== -1){
      const newObj = {...state.arr[pos]}
      newObj.values.push(value)
      state.arr.splice(pos, 1, newObj)
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Actually I used the `Vue.set` which worked as per my requirement. Added the code sample as an answer if required for your reference.